# subprocess popen real time output with timeout

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

After some research, I've been using subprocess.check_output() which accepts timeout parameter and raises TimeoutExpired if timeout for the command is reached. That's ok, but the limitation is that I'm not getting the real time output, so I am forced to use Popen directly, basically:

```
def execute_cmd(cmd, timeout=2):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
        print(line.rstrip().decode("utf-8"))
    p.stdout.close()
    retcode = p.wait()
```

How could I add a timeout in this block of code?

Comment: what do you mean by " I'm not getting the real time output" ?

Comment: The output is printed when the command finishes execution. If it takes 5 minutes, I have to wait until the end to see the full output. I want something similar to this example, where I can pull the output in "real time".

Comment: Sounds like you'll (also?) need a `readline` with a timeout. Regardless, I doubt this can ever be done in "real time" due to the nature of interprocess communication. Also, doing this in a non-platform specific way could also be very complicated as evidenced by the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/subprocess.py) of the subprocess module.

Comment: When I say "real time" I don't mean it strictly. At least, I want to see the output as if I was running the command manually. So, no waits until subprocess.run()/check_output() finishes.

Answer (score 6):

I finally came up with a solution with Timers. Not sure it's the best approach but it works..

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess
import time
from threading import Timer

def execute_bash_cmd(cmd, timeout=5):
    print("cmd: " + cmd)
    def timerout(p):
        print("Command timed out")
        timer.cancel()
        os.killpg(os.getpgid(p.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
        # or use p.kill() if shell==False

    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    timer = Timer(timeout, timerout, args=[p])
    timer.start()
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,b''):
        line = line.rstrip().decode("utf-8")
        print(line)
    p.stdout.close()
    retcode = p.wait()
    timer.cancel()
```

Examples:

```
execute_bash_cmd('ls -l /')
execute_bash_cmd('sleep 2', 3)
execute_bash_cmd('sleep 4', 3)
```

Output:

```
cmd: ls -l /
total 92
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb 18 15:28 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Feb 18 15:16 boot
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root  4020 Feb 18 15:43 dev
drwxr-xr-x 134 root root 12288 Feb 19 22:42 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Jun  7  2018 home
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 Feb 18 15:28 lib
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Feb 18 15:28 lib64
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Feb 18 13:12 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jun  7  2018 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Feb 18 15:26 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 247 root root     0 Feb 18 15:43 proc
drwx------  10 root root  4096 Feb 19 22:42 root
drwxr-xr-x  37 root root  1060 Feb 19 20:21 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 Feb 18 15:20 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jun  7  2018 selinux
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Feb 18 15:18 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root     0 Feb 19 22:42 sys
drwxrwxrwt  23 root root  4096 Feb 19 22:37 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Jun  7  2018 usr
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Feb 18 14:15 var

cmd: sleep 2

cmd: sleep 4
Command timed out
Terminated
```